# Network suddenly stopped working and adapter is gone in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, network-interface

After booting up a Arch Linux (vbox) machine, the network no longer works.

Ethernet adapters don't show up: Commands `ip a` and `ip link` only show loopack / localhost interface

Kernel module seems not to be properly loaded: `lspci -vnn` does list the interface but no kernel module or driver

How do I fix it? Why has this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
uname -a
pacman -Q linux
```

The output in a **healthy** machine should have matching version numbers:

```
linux 6.1.1.arch-1 # SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC [...]
linux 6.1.1.arch-1
```

In my case it was not: the second line, the version reported by `pacman -Q linux`, was higher: `6.1.5.arch-1` or similar. This means that the installed kernel package does not match the running one.

The solution is re-install the kernel package corresponding to the one reported by `uname`. And hope it's still in the cache.

First find the exact name with and note down the one that matches the uname verison:

```
ls /var/cache/pacman/pkg/linux-*
```

and then install the file you just found with:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/linux-6.1.1.arch-1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Network should work  now.

This probably happened the last time system update was run

(adapted from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224032))